# How to adjust standard errors in regression table (long text disrupting the formatting)?

Tags: tables, tabulary

When I am centering and formatting my regression table using tabulary, the text on the table causes the standard errors to appear much below the coefficient. I don't know how to adjust this. I have tried using different formats like longtable, table, and tabulary.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCCCCC} \toprule
 & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
VARIABLES & Contraceptive usage & children ideally & AIDS Awareness \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\
own\_tv & 0.07*** & -0.21*** & 0.17*** \\
 & (0.01) & (0.02) & (0.01) \\
Age & 0.07*** & 0.01 & 0.01*** \\
 & (0.00) & (0.01) & (0.00) \\
Newspaper regular Women = 2, Sometimes 2 & 0.04*** & 0.01 & 0.08*** \\
 & (0.01) & (0.03) & (0.01) \\
Newspaper regular Women = 3, Regularly 3 & -0.04** & -0.01 & 0.07*** \\
 & (0.02) & (0.03) & (0.01) \\
Radio regular Women = 2, Sometimes 2 & -0.04*** & 0.07*** & -0.02** \\
 & (0.01) & (0.02) & (0.01) \\
Radio regular Women = 3, Regularly 3 & -0.09*** & 0.09*** & -0.01 \\
 & (0.02) & (0.03) & (0.01) \\
Constant & -0.77*** & 1.95*** & 0.11** \\
 & (0.06) & (0.11) & (0.05) \\
 &  &  &  \\
Observations & 30,329 & 31,295 & 33,112 \\
 R-squared & 0.086 & 0.127 & 0.271 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you switch to a `tabularx` environment, allow automatic line breaking in the data columns, and employ a custom command -- called `\mytab` in the code below -- on the material in column 1 in order to avoid getting unwanted extra line breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,array,calc,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}L@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

%\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} 
%\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}

\begin{document}

%\centering % ??
\noindent
\begingroup 
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L *{3}{C{\widthof{Contraceptive}}} @{}} 
\toprule
 & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
Variables & Contraceptive usage & Children ideally & AIDS awareness \\ 
\midrule
Own\_tv & 0.07*** & -0.21*** & 0.17*** \\
 & (0.01) & (0.02) & (0.01) \\ \addlinespace
Age & 0.07*** & 0.01 & 0.01*** \\
 & (0.00) & (0.01) & (0.00) \\ \addlinespace
\mytab{Newspaper regular Women = 2, Sometimes 2} & 0.04*** & 0.01 & 0.08*** \\
 & (0.01) & (0.03) & (0.01) \\ \addlinespace
\mytab{Newspaper regular Women = 3, Regularly 3} & -0.04** & -0.01 & 0.07*** \\
 & (0.02) & (0.03) & (0.01) \\ \addlinespace
\mytab{Radio regular Women = 2, Sometimes 2} & -0.04*** & 0.07*** & -0.02** \\
 & (0.01) & (0.02) & (0.01) \\ \addlinespace
\mytab{Radio regular Women = 3, Regularly 3} & -0.09*** & 0.09*** & -0.01 \\
 & (0.02) & (0.03) & (0.01) \\ \addlinespace
Constant & -0.77*** & 1.95*** & 0.11** \\
 & (0.06) & (0.11) & (0.05) \\ \addlinespace
Observations & 30,329 & 31,295 & 33,112 \\
R-squared & 0.086 & 0.127 & 0.271 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{ *** $p<0.01$, ** $p<0.05$, * $p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabularx} \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a follow-up, whenever I recall a tabularx table to a beamer presentation using \input or \include, it never works. Is there any alternate command for putting tabularx table on beamer? (Putting \tiny makes the table lines longer)

Comment: @Eric - Not sure I follow you. Speaking for myself, I've used `tabularx` environments in plenty of my own `beamer` documents, and I have never experienced a "it never works" issue. Please post a new query, in which you illustrate how the problem arises in your `beamer`-class document, using a sample `tabularx` environments that "works" in an `article`-class document.